# Why is my MATLAB's bode plot wildly off?

Tags: matlab, transfer-function, state-space, bode

I will give out all the details in case it is relevant. I have a MIMO state space system. I find its bode plot using MATLAB and separately using Mathematica. The plot from MATLAB is wildly off compared to the correct bode plot. However, the Mathematica plot is quite close to the correct one. Here's the interesting thing. The transfer function whose bode plot is being taken in both the softwares is calculated to be the same. Have I made some mistake or is it numerical errors contributing to the problem? Here is relevant part of my code:

```
A=[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0;
    0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0;
    0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0;
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1;
    -297.3,163.5,0,0,0,0,0,0;
    162.9,-267.2,104.2,0,0,0,0,0;
    0,57.8,-74.2,16.4,0,0,0,0;
    0,0,16.4,-16.4,0,0,0,0];
B=[0,0,0,0,0;
    0,0,0,0,0;
    0,0,0,0,0;
    0,0,0,0,0;
    131.4,0.046,0,0,0;
    0,0,0.045,0,0;
    0,0,0,0.025,0;
    0,0,0,0,0.25];
S=[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0;
    0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0];
D=zeros(2,5);
sys=ss(A,B,S,D)
systf=tf(sys);
s1a1=systf(1,2);
bode(s1a1);
```

[[MATLAB plot which is way off the correct one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIsyB.png)][1][[Mathematica Plot which is quite close to the correct one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwsIz.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwsIz.png)

EDIT: The transfer function being plotted here is:
$$\frac{0.046s^6-5.522\times 10^{-17}s^5+16.46 s^4 - 1.748\times 10^{-14} s^3 + 880.1 s^2 - 7.808\times 10^{-14} s + 7108}{s^8 - 4.373\times 10^{-15} s^7 + 655.1 s^6 - 2.258\times 10^{-12} s^5 + 9.887\times 10^{4} s^4 - 2.144\times 10^{-10} s^3 + 3.43\times 10^{6} s^2 - 4.353\times 10^{-9} s + 2.069\times 10^{7}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the reason for the difference is the number of samples used in the plot, since the extreme points are likely going to infinity (or very large numbers) such that if less points are used, those large values are simply missed in the computation. If the OP uses the same number of points in each, then the same result should be achieved- and for all the points shown if they were super-imposed on each plot it would be clear that for the points given, the results are the same.

My first suspicion before the OP added the plots was that it was due to the units of the axis. That is not the case but leaving this part of my answer below as it is another common reason for Bode plot differences:

The units of the frequency axis should be confirmed as they could be in units of:

Continuous domain units of frequency:

Hertz, or cycles/sec

radians/sec

Discrete domain units of (normalized) frequency:

cycles per sample (unique domain is $[-1,1)$)

radians/sample (unique domain is $[-\pi, \pi)$)

Comment: Ah sorry. I forgot to add the plots. I am editing my question to add them and hopefully they will help. The frequency units in both are different and so thats not a concern. My concern is the magnitude values being very wrong.

Comment: @MadCon I see! and know why that is occuring, will update my answer

Comment: Thank you so much! Taking more number of points in the interval of interest did the trick.

Comment: I have observed that just like less points is bad, too many points also gives wrong plot. It seems that somewhere in the middle gives the best 'accurate' plot. Do you know of such a thing? If yes, could you please tell why does this happen?

Comment: Please define “wrong”- I don’t see your transfer function but if it has points where it goes to infinity then you will see that up to the point of round off error within the precision of the number type shown. I usually have a maximum and minimum “value of concern” given a dB scale and ensure I have enough points so that those number are exceeded where the transfer function is going to infinity or 0 and then rescale the vertical axis to that range

Comment: By wrong, I am referring to change in peak magnitudes and relative peak heights. While for 10000 points, I get max magnitude in negative dB, with 100000 points, I get max magnitude in positive dB, which is not correct, going by the source I am referring to.

Comment: I can’t comment on what is correct but it sounds exactly like what I am referring to - can you post the frequency domain transfer function systf in readable Mathjax equation form in your question? That will clear up what “correct is” but if it goes to positive dB with increasing points that all makes sense to me—- from the transfer function we can determine what the true max value is

Comment: Okay, I am adding the expression of the transfer function.

Comment: Great and show what can solve from that to be the max value and how your bode plots are conclusively incorrect

Comment: I have added the TF to question. But the TF has polynomials of degree 8 and 6, so it seems that I would have to use MATLAB to verify MATLAB itself.

Comment: No, use math (equations) not a discrete approximation. Show the equation for $H(s)$ and then take the derivative (in Laplace which means multiply by $s$, set that to 0 and substitute $s=j\omega$ to solve for the maximums and minimums in the frequency response (given by the roots of those polynomials). Once you have those given by $\omega_n$, plug that into $H(\omega_n$ to get the true max and min values. If it goes to infinity or 0 it will be clear by inspection of the transfer function (poles and zeros on the $j\omega$ axis.

Comment: Okay, I will do that.

Comment: I think I get my mistake now. Could you please tell me if this is correct? The transfer function will become unbounded at the frequencies corresponding to poles since this has poles on the imaginary axis. Hence in this case, increasing number of points gave me ever increasing peaks which is as expected. I was wrong in sticking to one of the plots as 'correct' because the correct one would have inf values at pole frequencies.

Comment: Yes that is correct